# html5-canvas: Conversion of Image file to DataURL throws Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to get the Base64/Data URL of a chosen image file in Javascript. The user basically selects an image via the File Input control and the Data URL is generated. However, I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on
>   'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type
>   '(HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or
>   ImageBitmap)'

HTML:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1">
    <div>
        <input type="file" id="imageinput" onchange="testit(event)" />
        <canvas width="300" height="300" id="mycanvas" style="display: none;"></canvas>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
function testit(event) {

            var myImage = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);

            var myCanvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');

            var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');

            ctx.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0);

            var mydataURL = myCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');

            alert(mydataURL);

        }
```

Why isn't this code working, guys?

Comment: you need to put that url on an img tag's src and then pass the img to the canvas to draw, once loaded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can not draw an image from url directly to canvas. You have to create a image element/object to do that.

```
var myCanvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    alert(myCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'));
};

img.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
```

Here we have created a `image` object and set the `src` to user selected image url. After the image is loaded we are adding it to the canvas.

**EDIT:**

Here we have one more problem. Whatever the image size is, you will always get 300x300 cropped dataurl of the image because of the static canvas width and height. So we can set the width and height to the canvas dynamically after the image loaded. We can use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` so that you can open and see the image from your console in your browser itself.

```
myCanvas.width = img.width;
myCanvas.height = img.height;
```

Here is the final code:

```
var myCanvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
    myCanvas.width = img.width;
    myCanvas.height = img.height;

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    console.log(myCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'));
};

img.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
```

Here is the fiddle (i have made the canvas visible so that you can see the whole image and width and height change in canvas):

**UPDATE:**

As @Kaiido mentioned, It will produce PNG image since the 'image/jpg' is not the mimetype. 'image/jpeg' is the mimetype for both JPG and JPEG images.

Updated Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/k7moorthi/r8soo95p/4/

Comment: Your code works well on fiddle. However when I added that to the header inside a <script> tag, I dont get any result. No alerts either. No errors either. I included the <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> script as well. Why is that?

Comment: No need for jquery. I added it in the fiddle for ease of use. You can do it with normal javascript itself. In your code just replace the function body with the final code in my answer's edit part. To see the result go to your browser console.

Comment: Works. Thanks for taking the time mate! Very helpful!

Comment: The correct parameter to get a JPEG version of `toDataURL()` is `"image/jpeg"`. The one OP and your code use is invalid and will return a png.

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to draw an object URL to the canvas. you need to create an image in memory first

http://jsfiddle.net/zmtu6t6c/4/

```
var myImageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
var myImage = new Image();
myImage.src = myImageUrl;

myImage.onload = function(){

... then do the canvas stuff

}
```

Comment: wait for load event isn't needed ?

Comment: For me the result is a white square 300*300